# Printing $node vars in page.tpl.php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

In Drupal's page.tpl.php

```
<?php foreach($node->og_groups as $test) {dpm($test);} ?>
```

Gives me
[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091229-ekf6xqg5dxq6cgjsgfty74umfx.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20091229-ekf6xqg5dxq6cgjsgfty74umfx.jpg)

But when I do

```
<?php foreach($node->og_groups as $test) {print($test);} ?>
```

The value doesn't show up. this is kinda frustating..
Any help is appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: What's the result of  `dvm($node->og_groups); foreach($node->og_groups as $test) {dvm($test);}` ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($test)` print?

Comment: var_dump($test); has no output at all,<br />
Confirmed it with dpm(var_dump($test));

Comment: Can you use `print` at all in this place? E.g. does `print('start'); foreach($node->og_groups as $test) {print('.');} print('end');` print anything?

Comment: sorry, I misread your previous question.  
The results for `dvm($node->og_groups); foreach($node->og_groups as $test) {dvm($test);}` is  
array(1) {
  [61]=>
  int(61)
}
int(61)       
and `print('start'); foreach($node->og_groups as $test) {print('.');} print('end');` gets `startend`

Comment: `print` is working fine though

Comment: should'n it be print $test (without parenthesis)?

Comment: @barraponto I think it's the same. Tried it though, returns nothing.

Answer (score 3):

As [Steve Michel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120773/steve-michel) suggested: Try doing a view source on the rendered page; it may be going to the top of the HTML and may not be visible in the browser output.

Drupal first executes all code, collecting output into a variable. At the very end, this variable is print out. If you print or var_dump something in between, this will be at the very top of the output (since that's done before any of the regular content is printed).

You even figured out the answer: use drupal_set_message (for which dpm is an abbreviation I guess?) to insert text in a nicely formatted way, somewhere in the content part of the page rather than before the  tag.

If you need to print out arrays, you can use `dpm(print_r($array, 1))` -- the 1 argument makes `print_r` *return* the formatted output (and pass it to `dpm`) rather than printing it out directly.

Comment: Hey Wim, thanks for your input.    
I have already given up on this method I'm trying.    
But for your info:    
`dpm()` is actually the drupal module(http://drupal.org/project/devel/) version of Krumo(http://krumo.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a view source on the rendered page; it may be going to the top of the HTML and may not be visible in the browser output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<?php foreach($node->og_groups as $test) print_r($test) ?>
```

Comment: Well, you can use debugger like xdebug or zend debugger to examine this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

> $node = $variables['node'];

and then use it like a normal node.